# Duplicating data when fetching JSON function called

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

My problem is I have the function `getData()` on the `ViewDidLoad()` and when i switch to another view and go back to this view it loads again the Data which duplicates my Data on the tableView.

```
var items = [Items]() 

func getData() {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
            self.obj.helper.checkConnectivity()

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)

                let jsonArray = json[].arrayValue
                for json in jsonArray {

                    let item = Items.fromJson(json: json)
                    self.items.append(item)
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }



struct Items {
    var id: Int
    var name: String

    static func fromJson(json: JSON) -> Items {
        return Items(
            id: json["id"].intValue,
            name: json["name"].stringValue,
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends. Why do you call it again? You are requesting the same data again, no? So avoid calling it again? Or are you looking for a paginated API ?

Comment: @Larme I'm calling the getData() on ViewDidLoad() so I'm just calling it once on the ViewController.

Comment: why are you reloading the page?  If it is loaded, and you navigate to another page and then return, you should just get viewDidAppear - are you forcing an unload of the view as part of your navigation?  If you need to unload the page, you should remove all of the data as part of the unload - if it's valid to keep the form data, you shouldn't be removing the form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert a line to clear the array:

```
... 
  let jsonArray = json[].arrayValue
  self.items.removeAll()
  for json in jsonArray {
...
```

---

or replace

```
for json in jsonArray {
    let item = Items.fromJson(json: json)
    self.items.append(item)
 }
```

with

```
self.items = jsonArray.map { Items.fromJson(json: $0) }
```

Comment: Thanks works with "self.items = jsonArray.map { Items.fromJson(json: $0) }"